# 960: help with not fixed size column

Tags: css, 960.gs

i want to have 5 divs (2 rows).

header
leftbar - content - rightbar - ad columns ( google adsense)

but i want the content to be resizable. it will adjust to the webbrowsers size but not undergo a certain width eg 600 px, while leftbar, rightbar and ad column are fixed. the header should also not be fixed.

just like [wn](http://www.wn.se/) (try to resize the webbrowser)

how do you accomplish this with 960? or do i have to code my own css?

Comment: Isn't it exactly 960's point that it's fixed to 960 pixels of width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to write your own css. Use min-width and max-width instead of width.
You probably want to set your header to max-width:960px and min-width to min width of content+fixed bars. And your content will be min-width:600px.

Comment: why should the header be has max-width. shouldnt it be like the content?